# "vector-effect" when set to non-scaling-stroke but scaled in parent div

Tags: svg, webkit, scaletransform

I want to keep the stroke width of svg even if the parent is scaled.

I was trying the code like below;

```
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
    <rect vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x="-20" y="-20" width="40" height="40" rx="5" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></rect>
</svg>
```

and the above works great, but what I want to do is like below;

```
<div style="-webkit-transform: scale(5,5);">
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
    <rect vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x="-20" y="-20" width="40" height="40" rx="5" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></rect>
</svg>
</div>
```

So if the parent dive is scaled by 5, the output of the stroke is also scaled by 5.
I want to keep the stroke width of the rect to fixed size of 2 even the parent div is scaled. May I get help?

Comment: no, you can't. You can dynamically change it in this case.